# Running a scanner program

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to write a program that basically will read any integer from 1,000 to 999,999 and will then display it with a comma separating the thousands. So far I have this, and eclipse doesn't like it. Why?

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone
{
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
// Scanner scan = new scanner(system.in);
double value, integer;
System.out.println("Enter your value without a comma");
integer = scan.nextdouble();
System.out.println(integer,);
scan.close();
```

Comment: I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hi Kyle, welcome to stackoverflow :) You should learn to read the compiler errors. It may seem cryptic at first, but it's definitely worth it.

The errors for this probably indicate at least the lines where the errors are occurring, which could help you investigate what the problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a lot of errors in the code which is why eclipse doesnt like it ;)

To name a few:

- new scanner -> Scanner with capital S
- system.in -> same with system

check out this snippet below and it will run just fine :)

```
/* package whatever; // don't place package name! */

import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;

/* Name of the class has to be "Main" only if the class is public. */
class Ideone {

public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    double value, intValue;

    System.out.println("Enter your value without a comma");

    intValue = scan.nextDouble();

    System.out.println(intValue);

    scan.close();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that helps a lot! All of this is a lot to take in but I am sure with practice I will get it. Thanks a lot, and thanks to everyone else as well for their input.

Comment: @KyleH Hi Kyle, remember to use CTRL+SPACE to use the auto-correct function. For example if you type in "syso" and hit CTRL+SPACE you will get a clear line with System.out.println();

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty problematic, to say the least. First of all, is the line in which you declare the Scanner supposed to be commented? If not, that could be part of the problem. You should watch out that you pass the upper-case `System.in` to your Scanner. You also want to use the `nextDouble()` method. (Java is case sensitive!) You also want to be careful in your second print statement that you do something more like `System.out.println(integer+",");`

Answer (score 1):

So, first, the solution:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ideone {

     public static void main(String[] args) {
         Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter a number:");
         long number = scan.nextLong();
         NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);
         System.out.println(f.format(number));
         scan.close();
     }

}
```

And the problems with you code:

- the package declaration is commented, why ?
- you import `java.lang.*` but you don't use it.
- your main method throws `java.lang.Exception`, but I don't see anything in your code throwing that.
- you have commented out the `scan` declaration.
- `scanner` should have the first letter uppercase (java is case-sensitive), same thing for `system`
- you declare a `double` called `value`, but you don't use it.
- you declare a `double` called `integer` (when what you really want is an integer).
- you use `scan.nextdouble()` instead of `scan.nextDouble()` (but remember, you want an integer, so you should call `scan.nextInt()`).
- I don't see any code trying to put a "," in your number.
- you print `integer,`, this is not even close to what you want, you could have tried `integer+","` to concatenate, but it's also not what you want.
- you are missing the closing brackets.
- the indentation of your code is really bad.

You should have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info in the section **Beginners' resources**, and try to understand a little bit more and to solve some of your problems by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for explaining why my code was wrong. I realize I should have reserved asking this question as a last resort, but I just didn't know where else to go and sometimes having the solution explained to you as such is really nice.

Answer (score 0):

Why have you commented the scanner instantiation, also I see the typo in there. The compiler will throw an exception on uninitialized 'scan' object.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(system.in);
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Micah answer, I would suggest you do a check on the input from users to check the range 1000 - 999,999 and re-prompt the user to input the value, if not it will beat the purpose of the range.

```
System.out.println("Enter your value without a comma");
integer = scan.nextDouble();
while (integer > 999999 OR integer < 1000)
{
      System.out.println("Please keep your range in between 1000 - 999,999");
      integer = scan.nextDouble();
}
```